# THYMELEAF - FRAGMENT TAG REMOVED

Tags: thymeleaf

I'm trying to replace a tag with a fragment of a template. After the inclusion, some part of the HTML code is removed

In my root page, I have

```
<p th:replace="mycomponent::firstFragment" th:with="myVar=#{'Hello'}"></p>
```

in my template I have

```
<p th:fragment="firstFragment" th:utext="#{someText}"><span th:utext="${myVar}"></span></p>
<p th:fragment="secondFragment"  th:utext="#{someOtherText}"><span ></span>${otherVar}</p>
```

The outcome is only the p element of the fragment without the inside span. I've tried with `th:inline="text"` but maybe I used it in a wrong way

Answer (score 0):

you can try `th:include` code. example .....

```
<span th:include="fragments/navbar::navbarPortion" th:remove="tag"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, seems that the issue is not related to the type of inclusion (insert, include or replace). But something to inline HTML code.
Here a guide to resolve it in two different ways

https://blog.abelotech.com/posts/thymeleaf-html-element-replacement/